# Signing up Codewars - Java Exercise

Tags: java

The code is

```
public class Multiply
{
   public static Double multiply(Double a, Double b)
   {
       return a * b
   }
}
```

I cannot solve the above code.
I tried a few things, like

```
public class Multiply 
{ 
   public double multiply(double a, double b) 
   { return a * b;} 
}
```

It still shows errors in code.
Kindly help, please.

Comment: What is the error?  What is the goal of the exercise?

Comment: You have provided little important information. Read the guide on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You essentially had the answer Codewars wanted. I imagine they expected for you to just add the semicolon, as you did, but keep the rest of the code the same.

```
public class Multiply
{
   public static Double multiply(Double a, Double b)
   {
       return a * b;
   }
}
```

I went to try it out, and this worked for me. Looks like they wanted you to keep `static` and the wrapper class `Double`.

Comment: Nice Job .That will be done. But then its goes to another page for the Another code.

Comment: I believe that there are multiple questions you must answer to register for the website. This was only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
public class Multiply 
{ 
   public double multiply(double a, double b) 
   { return a * b;} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about how it will work if it is executed without any `main` method and what all things are missing / incorrect format in the code

E.g. Where you can add any double value

```java
public class Multiply {
    public static double multiply(double a, double b) {
        return a * b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double result = multiply(20.01, 10.10);
        System.out.println("The result is: " + result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Multiply {
public double multiply(double a , double b )
//just change the wrapper to primitive
{     
     return a*b ;
   // add semicolon over here that it 
}
```

Comment: Assuming you're allowed to change the wrapper in the first place. Also, the `static` is no longer there, which may cause issues.